# How can I set variable in php and use it in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I made a function that is supposed to download html with all javascript results, but I am having a little problem, because I don'n know how I can send the url I am working with to the javascript function.
The files look like this:

PHP Function:

```
public function getHTML($url) {
    $script_direction = str_replace('\classes', '', dirname(__FILE__)) . '\phantomjs\phantomjs.js';
    $row = array();
    exec(str_replace('\classes', '', dirname(__FILE__)) . '\phantomjs\phantomjs ' . $script_direction, $row);
    $html = implode('', $row);
    return $html;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open(url, function(status) {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I need to the $url variable and send it to the javascript file and store it as url variable there.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a variable between php and JS like this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.yoursite.com";
?>

<script>
var url = <?=json_encode($url)?>;
<script>
```

---

As commented by @ceejayoz, using `json_encode()` will ensure the a single quote `'` in PHP doesn't break the JS.

Comment: `var url = <?= json_encode($url) ?>;` will ensure a `'` in your PHP variable doesn't break your JS.

Comment: Updated your update as `'<?=json_encode($url)?>'` will result in extra quotes - `json_encode` adds its own quotes around a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the variable on the page with PHP to a javascript variable like this:

```
<script>
    var url = <?php echo json_encode($url); ?>
</script>
```

Your PHP variables are not directly accessible through JS

EDIT: Added json_encode per @ceejayoz comment.

Comment: This will not work, it'll cause a JS error because the code will be `var url = http://example.com/;`. Wrap the `$url` in `json_encode()` to properly output it as a JS string.

Comment: Right. My bad. Edited the answer. Nice catch :)

Comment: "If it was a string, you could also put it in quotes" Only if you escape quotes in the string. Safer to always do `json_encode` in case someone gives you a URL like `http://example.com/something'here`.

Comment: Yes, which escaping should be standard practice for almost every user-input variable.

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting down-voted with a correct answer. The solution was a little off and was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put the url in data attribute on the html view, for example:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-url="<?=json_encode($url);?>">
```

And with javascript, jquery, etc... you can get it:

```
var url=$("#mydiv").data("url");
```

Comment: David, I edited your question to make it safer. Why'd you edit it back?

Comment: Because you add json_encode, I'm not write this. Only save a sting variable in a data attribute, not a json object

Comment: David, try it and see. If passed a string, `json_encode` will output a JavaScript string, with proper escaping. It's the safest way to output a PHP variable for use in JS. Without it, `$url` containing a `"` would break your site's HTML.

Comment: I understant you,  to scape  characters like http:\/\/

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use Ajax For This . for example this code uses jquery get method:

server.php :

```
$url = 'someUrl';
if(isset($_GET)){
if($_GET['request']=='get_url'){
     echo $url;
   }
}
```

Javascript Code:

```
    $.get('server.php',{request : 'get_url'},function(data){
    var url = data;
    });
```